# Is "let x = 3;;" an expression?

Tags: ocaml

People say everything in ocaml is an expression and has a type. But how can I understand a statement like

```
let x = 3;
```

and

```
let y = x * x;
```

These do not look like expressions, right?

Comment: You're right, `let` without `in` is not an expression. One way to think about it is that `let x = 3;; (remainder of the program)` works like `let x = 3 in (remainder of the program)`. See also this explanation about it: [cornell.edu: `let` definitions and `let` expressions](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/basics/let_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCaml expression are presented here https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html, and what you have typed is not expressions but let-bindings.

Beware, a single `;` is used to separate expressions and is typically used with imperative expressions.

Don’t confuse with `;;`

Answer (score 2):

They are not expressions, no, but they're also not statements. They're definitions. And there are other kinds of definitions as well, such as type and module definitions.

What is meant by "everything is an expression" is that everything **that is code** is an expression. That is, everything that results in executing some instruction. Another way of phrasing it that might be clearer when coming from C-like imperative languages is simply that "there are no statements".

Although it might look like there are statements, because the semicolon, `;`, is used in a similar way. But by implication of there not being any statements, `;` is not a statement terminator as in C-like languages, but a sequence operator. `a; b` is an expression composed of the sub-expressions `a` and `b`, where `a` is expected to evaluate to `unit` and by implication be pure side-effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But you said in "a;b", "a" needs to " evaluate to unit and by implication be pure side-effect."  I think evaluating to unit does not prevent us from having side effects, e.g.  updating a reference, no?

Comment: It doesn't no. It just means that even pure side-effects nee to evaluate to some value, and by convention that value is of type `unit`.

Comment: Note that in `a; b`< `a` _should_ evaluate to `unit` and doing otherwise will result in a compiler _warning_ but it will not result in a compiler _error_. E.g. `let () = (42; print_endline "Hello world!")` will compile and run.